# How to get month name from month number in Power BI?

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi, dax

I have Year number and Month Number in my data. 
How using DAX can I get the month name out of month number?

In SSRS its very easy. But how to achieve that using DAX?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the first google response: https://daxtips.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/get-month-name-from-a-date-field/. It says use the `FORMAT` function. Does this work for you?

Comment: You can get the month name from the date using the following formula: FORMAT([Date], "MMM")

Comment: I checked all responses. But I dont have date, I have number. So I need simply pass the number and return month name.

Comment: And of course I can get a date and get a month name from the source, but I'm just curious how would it be without the date. Learning process.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use:

```
MonthName = FORMAT(DATE(1, [Num], 1), "MMM")
```

Result:

[image: result]

Nothing fancy, simply a reconstruction of a fake date from the month number provided, and reformat it with the `FORMAT` function.

Of course as an alternative you can go the old-fashioned way and write a `SWITCH` statement and hard-coded for the 12 months. It's up to you.

Comment: To get the full name of the month you can use "MMMM" instead of "MMM" as as the format string

Comment: I am getting format is not a function. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this too:

Month name = FORMAT('Table'[date_column], "MMM")

If you use single quotes in 'MMM', it doesn't work. Ensure to use ""

Answer (score 0):

By Use of Switch DAX function
MonthName = switch(True(),
MonthID = 1, "jan",MonthID = 2, "Feb",MonthID = 3, "March",MonthID = 4, "April",MonthID = 5, "May",MonthID = 6, "June",MonthID = 7, "july",MonthID = 8, "Aug",MonthID = 9, "Sept",MonthID = 10, "Oct",MonthID = 11, "Nov",MonthID = 12, "Dec"
)

Answer (score 0):

u can use the Transform Value after you duplicate the Date Column and change the Day to Day Name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).